# Is it possible to showing image in input text field before sending it?

Tags: jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm working on getting JSQMessagesViewController to send media messages that contain URLs that reference an image, which gets saved to a backend service. After I select an image from the camera roll, is there some way to display it in the input text field before it is sent?

Also, can text and an image be combined in a single message? It seems like media messages just contain a media item, such as an image, and text messages just contain text.

Thanks,

Larry

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?